# Pass React Native View to Android

Tags: android, react-native

For my React Native Android component, I need a ViewGroup to attach on.

I saw that the  component from react native itself is a kind of ViewGroup implementation, but how can I pass it to my Android component? 
I tried with `AndroidNativeModule.init(new View())` and `AndroidNativeModule.init(<View/>)` but no luck.

An other option is to create a separate UI module for this but I think this is a little overkill?

*Some extra information*: I have a very specific camera module in Android, that I want to use in RN. To initialize that camera module, I need a ViewGroup to attach to (Camera 1 API needs a ViewGroup to attach a SurfaceView). So a I need to pass a Viewgroup. 
As a workaround, I created a custom Android UI View and passed the whole custom View to RN. It works this way but it would be nice to only use the logic from the Android module, and not the custom created View.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do. Do you want your RN component to be a part of an Android ViewGroup? What is `AndroidNativeModule`? Do you have more code you can post?

Comment: I've added some extra information, hope that clears out the situation. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Thanks. My understanding now is that your camera module is Java, and that you want to use it within a React Native view. Off the top of my head it seems to me your approach with a custom Android UI view is the way to go. That view could be either your entire camera UI or (I suppose) just a viewgroup that you can somehow use to attach your SurfaceView...